# how to make a discord bot delete what you wrote and send what you originally sent in javascript?

Tags: discord, discord.js

it should delete my message and type it as if it has said it itself, im a begginer in discord bot coding pls help

Comment: 1, save the message content to a variable 2, delete original one 3, send the message

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by storing the message in a variable, deleting the message, then sending the variable. An example would be:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
    const content = message.content;
    await message.delete();
    await message.channel.send(content);
});
```